# Copy / paste macro from excel to SAP VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I need to do a mass change in SAP. Therefore I would like to have a macro that copies 3 different columns from excel into sap (about 3000 rows)

Sales order # - Data 1 - Data 2

Copy sales order from excel - do transaction /nva02 - paste

copy Data 1 in excel - paste in Sap

copy Data 2 in excel - paste in Sap

And if possible to have an additional column to confirm if order has been updated (ok)

Next sales order etc until last row

The excel sheet will be used by multiple people users Something like Active workbook would be more helpful than a path

Could you please help providing a VBA code I know how to do Script recording in SAP

Thanks a lot in advance

Alex

Answer (score 0):

Check this tutorial in youtube called:
SAP GUI Scripting 1 - Running scripts from Excel
you will get all the answers

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oPPhA14Pm-8